# What is the sender IP address used for in an ARP REQUEST packet?

Tags: networking, ip, wireshark, tcp, arp

So in an ARP request packet, we have "Who has 192.168.1.1?  Tell 192.168.1.143". The reply however is not "sent" to the IP address 192.168.1.143, but to the MAC address associated with it. What is the purpose of having the sender's IP address?

Thanks.

Comment: The target protocol address (ip address) _is_ present in the response. Not sure why, though.

Comment: It does serve the purpose of piggybacking the requestor's own IP/MAC pair onto the request.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the piggybacking?

Comment: If 192.168.0.1 gets the request "who is 192.168.0.1? Tell 192.168.0.2" from the mac adress FE:ED:A0:07:BA:BE, then it learns that 129.168.0.2 is FE:ED:A0:07:BA:BE, and does not need to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is so people can reply to you without having to also send an ARP request.

In general there is a lot of redundant stuff in [the ARP rfc](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc826), but this particular thing seems alright to me.

> **The sender hardware address and sender protocol address are absolutely
> necessary.  It is these fields that get put in a translation table.**
> The target protocol address is necessary in the request form of the
> packet so that a machine can determine whether or not to enter the
> sender information in a table or to send a reply.  It is not
> necessarily needed in the reply form if one assumes a reply is only
> provoked by a request.  It is included for completeness, network
> monitoring, and to simplify the suggested processing algorithm
> described above (which does not look at the opcode until AFTER putting
> the sender information in a table).